# restricting number of users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, licensing

Our Ruby on Rails product is sold and installed on third parties. 
Is there any secured way to license and restrict the app for certain number of users? 
Considering that the client has full access to the sources?
One way I could think of is to use [source encryptor](http://rubyencoder.com/), but this is over-kill solution which the product owner doesn't want.

Comment: what do you mean by "restrict the app for certain number of users"? Its the number of simultaneous users or the number of registered users?

Comment: Number of registered users.

Answer (score 3):

in short, if the customer has the source code, they can edit out any protection you wish to put there. incl. Pablo's option on a module in a different language. This is probably why most subscription software products developed in Ruby (and other scripting languages) are sold as a SAAS, which means the customer has no access to the source code.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I think so also. I'm looking for a solution that will make it hard to break, not the perfect solution. One way is to encode the whole project with the ruby encoder I mentioned above, so it will be impossible to reverse engineer the logic but they don't want this solution. BTW, this product has ability to act as SAAS but there are government organisations that need their own installation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to implement an license manager and let your application make an API call to know if it can continue. 
There are several ways to implement this, like tokens or timestamps, where your application validates them before proceeding.

But you need to be conscious that if your costumer has access to the source code, it be edited. If you want to ensure that nobody messes with you license scheme, create a C/C++ module and use it in you ruby code.

Comment: But if I have full access I can enter rails console and do what ever I want anyway.